# JSfiddle - add fonts from icomoon

Tags: fonts, icons, jsfiddle

I wanted to post a problem I am having with icomoon icons.... and to show you the problem I wanted to do it on jsfiddle but now I am stuck.

How can I add the font files like icomoon.eot, icomoon.svg etc etc in JSfiddle? To be able to post my real problem here...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Paste the href part of the CDN link

```
//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

To External Resourses on the left side pane and click the plus sign

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/karin/804jeg82/1/)

Comment: sorry, I've edited the mistake. The problem is with icomoon. when I generate the icons, icomoon gives me a zip, with the font files as icomoon.eot, icomoon.svg, icomoon.ttf and icomoon.woff, and a css file. The css obvious, I just have to paste it on the css in the JSfiddle, but my question is, how can I add the font files? As without them the css does not work as it needs to look for those src.

Comment: can't you link them in the css file

    @font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('http://www.the-annett.com/jsfiddle/fonts/icomoon.eot'); /*change to your own font location*/
    src:url('http://www.the-annett.com/jsfiddle/fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('http://www.the-annett.com/jsfiddle/fonts/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg'),
        url('http://www.the-annett.com/jsfiddle/fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('http://www.the-annett.com/jsfiddle/fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype');

Comment: But..... how to I include them in JSFiddle? Because if I change the src url only... they won't be there, no?